# How can I access these field in testing ( Flutter)?

Tags: testing, flutter

I have these fields below in-state class and I want to test if these fields work correctly. So I write testing dart file, how can I access these field in a testing file

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
      String _phoneNumber = "";
  String _smsCode = "";
  String _verificationId = "";
  int _currentStep = 0;

  List<StepState> _stepsState = [
    StepState.editing,
    StepState.indexed,
    StepState.indexed
  ];

  bool _showProgress = false;
  String _displayName = '';
  File _imageFile;

  bool _labeling = false;

  List<ImageLabel> _labels = List();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@visibleForTesting` annotation from any of these packages

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
```